# Hide/show ImageView from a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to hide/show imageview from a custom listview base on the condition. However, trying the below code is not hiding/showing the imageview based on the condition. As you can see below inside **mainactivity.java** I have a String variable **message** now inside the **private ArrayList generateData()** method I have set **message=nopic/message=yespic**. I am passing the String value (value of message) to my custom adapter. Then inside my custom adapter if message=="nopic" hide the imageview from the listview else show imageview in listview.

I have tried the following code but it's not hiding the imageview instead all the imageview are shown.

Can you help me achieve this please

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

{

```
private String[] fruits = 
    {
        "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Grapes", "Straberries", "Pineapple", "Berry"
    };

private String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Item> items=generateData();

    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),items, message);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private ArrayList<Item> generateData()
{     
    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),null, null);

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();  
    for(int i=0; i<fruits.length; i++)
    {

        if(fruits[i].toString().equals("Grapes"))
        {
            message = "nopic";
            items.add(new Item("Grapes sweet", null));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            message = "yespic";
            items.add(new Item(fruits[i].toString(), null));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }            
    return items;       
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;
    public String message;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList, String message) {

        super(context, R.layout.row, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
        this.message = message;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);


        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 

        title.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        if(message == "nopic")
        {
            pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        if(message == "yespic")
        {
            pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search);
        }

        return rowView;

    }
```

Comment: `if(message == "nopic")`. You mean: `if(message.equals( "nopic"))`. `inside mainactivity.java` Please do not make that bold. Instead write it normally as `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: What is purpose of this 'MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),null, null);' ? And this adapter is not attached to your ListView.

Comment: In generateData() just fill ArrayList and do nothing more, return filled list from generateData() function, then put this list into Adapter constructor, attach adapter to ListView and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: And you need some yespic/nopic flag for every item in your ListView, don't use one global variable String message. Just put this flags inside next list in adapter or in the same list `new Item("Grapes sweet", true)`, or `new Item("Grapes sweet", false)`

Comment: @tomm sorry I don't know how to use flags can you please show me. Do you mean something like boolean?

Comment: yes boolean, i dont know what is second parameter in Item constructor, but if it is possible add this boolean flag instead of null value

Comment: @tomm this is a great solution thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
message == "yespic";
```

Try

```
message.equals("yespic");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

every time you change the content of a listView.